# xhr request on iOS fails unexpectedly

Tags: javascript, ios, xmlhttprequest

Has anyone experienced an issue with iOS where the XHR request simply fails without notifying the initiator of the request?

[image: Screen Shot 2019-03-25 at 5 44 28 PM]

[image: 54909881-22a37500-4f26-11e9-8789-72e8a1d811ad]

The only feedback I get is the error message seen above that says "Error loading resources". My guess is that it has something to do with the way I handle xhr request. All my XHR requests are on a separate thread (web workers).

I don't think that the web worker fails to load because I'm already seeing the worker's console logs on the console.

NOTES:

- I am using [Axios](https://github.com/axios/axios).
- The issue is intermittent.

This happens to google.com too when using the same device. I'm using a simulator, iphone 5s ios version 12.1

[image]

[image]

[image]

Even weirder is this, I got the response with 200 response code, somehow I'm not able to get the actual response data itself and the error happens.

[image: Screen Shot 2019-03-25 at 7 03 10 PM]

[image: Screen Shot 2019-03-25 at 7 05 50 PM]

---

I also posted this here https://github.com/scottjehl/Device-Bugs/issues/79